# Discrepancy in the number of simplices in the barycentric subdivision of an $n$-simplex

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, oeis

According to OEIS, the number of simplices in the barycentric subdivision of an $n$-simplex is either given by the sequence:

1. ([A002050](https://oeis.org/A002050)): 1, 5, 25, 149, 1081, 9365, 94585, 1091669, 14174521, 204495125, etc.; OR
2. ([A005461](https://oeis.org/A005461)): 1, 15, 180, 2100, 25200, 317520, 4233600, 59875200, 898128000, etc.

Despite them both having the description "Number of simplices in barycentric subdivision of $n$-simplex," these appear to be very different sequences.

However, I don't immediately see why this is the case, seeing as the terms of the sequences appear to differ by quite a lot. What is causing the difference in these two sequences, and is one of them more "correct" than the other?

Comment: @Somos I have removed the incorrect statement, though I don't see why that would invalidate the question as a whole.

Comment: Okay. Now close vote retracted.

Comment: The first is the one that makes sense to me.  I don't know in what sense the subdivision of a 1-simplex could have 15 simplices.

Comment: It's also strange that some of the terms in the second sequence are even.  *No* triangulation of a simplex can have an even number of simplices, since the Euler characteristic must be 1.

Comment: It seems the second sequence is based off these [unpublished notes from 1987](https://oeis.org/A000629/a000629.pdf), though I could not make heads or tails of them so far. I think, maybe, this sequence is counting the number of simplices *added* to the original simplex after taking the barycentric subdivision. But then again, that still doesn't explain $15$ simplices in the subdivision of a $1$-simplex. Hmph...

Comment: As far as I can tell the second sequence is $1$, followed by the number of $n$-simplices in the barycentric subdivision of an $(n + 3)$-simplex, see eq (6) on page 4 of the pdf you linked.

Comment: @ronno So the second term should be the number of $2$-simplices in the barycentric subdivision of a $5$-simplex (2+3)? Unless I misunderstand....

Comment: $15$ is the number of $0$ simplices in the subdivision of a $3$ simplex and $180$ is the number of $1$ simplices in the subdivision of a $4$ simplex and so on.

Comment: @ronno ah, i see now. the sequence description is highly misleading then